# Tunnel all my traffic through a VPS IP (VPN)

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a windows PC with SoftEther VPN. I also have a VPS. How exactly would I turn the VPS in to a VPN so all the windows traffic is tunneled through it? This would result in my Windows PC having the IP address of the VPS.
Note: I currently "rent" a dedicated IP from a third party service and use SoftEther to tunnel all the traffic through it. However I would like to learn to do this myself and have control over everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can install some VPN-server packages like `wireguard` or `openvpn`.

I personally use **WireGuard** due to some reasons using UDP packets.

You can download the script via this link: https://github.com/Nyr/wireguard-install

Installation:

```
wget https://git.io/wireguard -O wireguard-install.sh && bash wireguard-install.sh
```

Then choose a DNS server and a name, and boom! That's done.

You also can use this on your smartphone or either laptop/PC.

Download WireGuard client on your Windows: https://www.wireguard.com/install/